# React/Rails AJAX POST request returns 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to wire up this AJAX POST request in my react component to communicate with my rails api controller. The console logs a 404 error and I can't seem to hit the pry.

## react/src/pages/HomeIndex.js

```
  getCompare() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/sources/compare',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {value: this.state.inputValue, from: this.state.compareFrom, to: this.state.compareTo },
      contentType: 'application/json'
    })
  }
```

## controllers/api/sources_controller.rb

```
  def compare
    binding.pry
  end
```

## config/routes

```
  post '/api/sources/compare', to: 'api/sources#compare'

  namespace :api do
    resources :sources, only: [:index, :compare]
  end
```

## rake routes

```
api_sources_compare POST /api/sources/compare(.:format) api/sources#compare
```

## update

I tried updating the routes with several permutations...

```
  namespace :api do
    resources :sources, only: [:index] do
      collection do
        post :compare
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :api do
    resources :sources, only: [:index, :compare] do
      collection do
        post :compare
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :api do
    resources :sources, only: [:index] do
      collection do
        resources :compare, only: [:compare]
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :api do
    resources :sources do
      post :compare
    end
  end
```

...all with the same outcome.

Comment: Can you post your rails console error log?

Comment: I'm not getting any rails console error. The ajax call is never reaching rails. It is being made in react and returns a 404 in the console.

Comment: So, the request is not reaching rails server with an invalid route? can you check your network tab (dev tool) and see which url is being sent?

Comment: The console reads `POST http://localhost:3000/api/sources/compare 400 (Bad Request)`. The network tab shows a bad call to compare `Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/sources/compare
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:[::1]:3000`

Comment: I think you cannot set `:compare` to a "only" option. Remove the first `post` definition and use `collection do ... end` in `resources`

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got the same outcome. Question updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by stringifying your AJAX payload, as follows:

```js
getCompare() {
    let data = JSON.stringify({value: this.state.inputValue, from: this.state.compareFrom, to: this.state.compareTo })
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/sources/compare',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      contentType: 'application/json'
    })
  }
```